# determining modulus of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

This is my complex number: $z =(\sqrt 3 − i)^{-10}$

I must represent it in the form $a + bi$.

In my answer sheet, they represent the modulus $|z|= \sqrt{3+1} = 2$. I know in general modulus is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Where do they get $3$ and $1$ from the original formula??

Thanks.

Comment: Was that exponent $-10$ or $10$?

Comment: the exponent is **-10**

Comment: The modulus, according to the formula, would be $\sqrt{(\sqrt 3)^2+(-1)^2}=2$ of the number $\sqrt 3 - i$.  The value of $|z|$ will be something else.

Comment: Please review my edits to your question and consider the use of $\LaTeX$ and/or MathJAX in place of symbols.

Comment: Ok i'll do that thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The absolute value:

$$|\text{z}|=\left|\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{-10}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}}\right|=\frac{\left|1\right|}{\left|\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}\right|}=\frac{1}{\left|\sqrt{3}-i\right|^{10}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2+1^2}\right)^{10}}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{3+1}\right)^{10}}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{4}\right)^{10}}=\frac{1}{2^{10}}=\frac{1}{1024}$$

- The argument:

$$\arg\left[\text{z}\right]=\arg\left[\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{-10}\right]=$$
$$\arg\left[\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}}\right]=\arg\left[1\right]-\arg\left[\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}\right]=$$
$$0-\arg\left[\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}\right]=-\arg\left[\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}\right]=-\arg\left[\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{10}\right]=$$
$$-\arctan\left[\cos(10\arg(\sqrt{3}-i)),\sin(10\arg(\sqrt{3}-i))\right]=$$
$$-\arctan\left[\cos\left(10\cdot-\frac{\pi}{6}\right),\sin\left(10\cdot-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right]=$$
$$-\arctan\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$

So:

$$\text{z}=\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{-10}=\frac{1}{1024}\cdot e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}=\frac{1}{2048}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2048}i$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt3-i=2e^{-\frac{\pi i}6}\implies\left(\sqrt3-i\right)^{-10}=2^{-10}e^{\frac{5\pi i}3}$$

In rectangular form:

$$e^{\frac{5\pi i}3}=\cos\frac{5\pi i}3+i\sin\frac{5\pi i}3=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$

Comment: how does one get an angel of $ \pi / 6$, I get $ arctan(\frac{-1}{sqrt{3}}) $

Comment: @matttm $$\arctan\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}=\arctan\frac{-1/2}{\sqrt3/2}=\arctan\frac{\sin\left(-\frac\pi6\right)}{\cos\left(-\frac\pi6\right)}=-\frac\pi6$$

Answer (score 2):

$z = (\sqrt 3 - i)^{-10}$

convert $\sqrt 3 - i$ to polar form:

$\sqrt 3 - i = \rho (\cos \theta\ + i \sin \theta)$

$\rho = |\sqrt 3 - i|$

$\sqrt 3 - i = 2 (\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} - i\frac{1}{2})$

$\sqrt 3 - i = 2 (\cos \frac{-\pi}{6} + i\sin \frac{-\pi}{6})$

$z = (2 (\cos \frac{-\pi}{6} + i\sin \frac{-\pi}{6}))^{-10}$

$z = (2^{-10} (\cos \frac{5\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{5\pi}{3}))$

Comment: You've conflated $z$ with $\sqrt 3-i$, but these are different numbers...  Of course, the OP (or at least the representation of the answer sheet) has done the same.

Comment: Yah z= (√3 - i)^-10

Comment: Indeed.  I will edit and repost.